# converting many lists into single dict

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a function which loops, and prints many, arbitrary number of separate lists.

example:

**EDIT**: This is the output I get when I run my function.

```
['Hello', 'Mello', 'Jello']
['Sun', 'Fun', 'Run']
['Here', 'There', 'Everywhere'}
```

Now I would like to convert these arbitrary separate lists into a dict such as this:

```
{'Hello':['Sun','Here'], 'Mello':['Fun', 'There'], 'Jello':['Run', 'Everywhere']}
```

Where each of the elements in the first list become the 'keys' and the all the elements under become the 'values' (or is it the otherway around?)...

What I tried was:

```
{k:v for k, *v in zip(*data)}
```

But when I do this, I get an output something like this:

```
{'1': ('T', 'P', '2'), '7': ('a', '.', '6'), '9': ('t', 'r', '8')}
{'0': ('h', 'L', '1'), '2': ('T', 'N', '1')}
{'0': ('o', 'V', '0'), '2': ('T', 'B', '1')}
```

Comment: P.S these are separate lists

Comment: The problem is with your data, the method works fine.

Comment: How does `row` relate to `data`?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> L1 = ['Hello', 'Mello', 'Jello']
>>> L2 = ['Sun', 'Fun', 'Run']
>>> L3 = ['Here', 'There', 'Everywhere']
>>> {k:v for k, *v in zip(L1, L2, L3)}
{'Hello': ['Sun', 'Here'], 'Mello': ['Fun', 'There'], 'Jello': ['Run', 'Everywhere']}
```

It's not clear what you had in `data`, but this works fine

```
>>> data = [L1, L2, L3]
>>> {k:v for k, *v in zip(*data)}
{'Hello': ['Sun', 'Here'], 'Mello': ['Fun', 'There'], 'Jello': ['Run', 'Everywhere']}
```

Other options are

```
>>> dict(map(lambda k, *v:(k, v), *data))
{'Hello': ('Sun', 'Here'), 'Mello': ('Fun', 'There'), 'Jello': ('Run', 'Everywhere')}



>>> dict(map(lambda k, *v:(k, list(v)), *data))
{'Hello': ['Sun', 'Here'], 'Mello': ['Fun', 'There'], 'Jello': ['Run', 'Everywhere']}
```

Comment: data is the : (for data in file)

Comment: the problem is... I cant label my lists L1, L2, L3 as it comes out of the loop? Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: @user3029969, you didn't show us how you are reading the file. That appears to be where your problem is. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: The labels are not important, the structure of `data` is important, and you didn't show us that

Comment: @user3029969, are we supposed to guess what's in the file? It's obviously different to the example data - contains numbers etc...

Comment: I get invalid syntax on `*v`. What does it do, and why do I get the error? (I'm on 2.7.5)

Comment: @KaranGoel, You can use one of the `dict(map...` versions

Comment: Yes. But I would still like to understand what the `*` does, and why it's throwing a syntax error. Is it a py 3 thing?

Comment: @KaranGoel, yes Python3 is a little more flexible with tuple unpacking (and more restrictive in some places too) `k, *v` means put the first item in `k` and the rest as a tuple into `v`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is something like this:

```
myLists = [ #lists you want to convert
    ['Hello', 'Mello', 'Jello']        
    ['Sun', 'Fun', 'Run']              
    ['Here', 'There', 'Everywhere']    
]
theDict = {} #where you will store the converted lists
for list in myLists: #for each list...
    theDict[list[0]] = list[1:] #set the dict's key to list[0] and contents to everything starting from index 1
```